# How do I get the rest of my catalog items back?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I ordered about 10 catalog items, but my mailbox was almost full. Later, I got some of my catalog items, but my mailbox was too full to fit the others in. I cleaned out my mailbox, but the other items I ordered **STILL** weren't there. How can I get them back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info on various forums, I would say you will get them the next time mail is delivered. Just wait a bit, deliveries are at 9 a.m and 5 p.m.

And from the official [FAQ](http://www.animal-crossing.com/newleaf/faq/) :

> If you still don't receive your orders, please check if the other players in your town have full mailboxes as well.